# php mail() recipient address missing

Tags: php, email, header

My website runs the following code: (I BCC myself so that I have a copy of all the emails that my website sends out)

```
//prepare email headers
$headers = "From: " . "info@mysite.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". "info@mysite.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: sent@mysite.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = getMsg( ... );
mail( $buyer_email, 'mysite.com - Verify your information.', $message, $headers );
$message = getMsg( ... );
mail( $seller_email, 'mysite.com - Verify your information.', $message, $headers );
```

The emails get sent out perfectly fine. The problem is with the second email that gets BCC'ed to me. The recipient's email address is blank so I can't see who the email was sent to. The first email that's BCC'ed to me is fine, all the info shows up. In other words, I can see $buyer_email, but I can't see $seller_email. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the rest of the code. What you've shown doesn't help troubleshoot.

Comment: Did you check if $seller_email is actually set to anything before sending the mail? even a simple `var_dump($seller_email)` before the mail() call would tell you.

Comment: Yes, I know $seller_email is valid because I'll plug one of my email addresses in there, and I receive the email.

Answer (score 2):

You can debug it like this

```
echo "Seller Email: $seller_email";
mail( $seller_email, 'mysite.com - Verify your information.', $message, $headers )
```

The page will print the seller email and you can see what it actually is.

### Addition

If you can not use the above code because you have to test it a user (which is normal btw), use the following technique.

Since you are getting the first email, send $seller_email as part of test code in that email and see what value it has.

```
$message = getMsg( ... );
mail( $buyer_email, "mysite.com - Test Seller Email: $seller_email .", $message, $headers );
```

You will find out the seller email value in the email you get.

Comment: That doesn't help me because I'm not the user.

Comment: Added to my question. Send $seller_email to yourself in the first email which is working.

Comment: Ok, you meant just to test. Yeah, I've done that. $seller_email is set properly. And whoever the seller is does receive the email. But the copy that gets BCC'ed to me is still missing that info.

Comment: interchange the order of the two mail() function. Mave the bottom at the top, see where the problem is now. Could be because the two are one after another.

Answer (score 1):

Does sending additional headers help? ([see mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)) That way you don't have to use 2 mail functions.

Like this:

```
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure what more headers I would add. I already have the BCC line in there. And I have 2 mail functions because I need to send 2 emails (1 to the buyer and 1 to the seller).

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry, but I made a huge mistake. Long story, but basically I was confusing code on one page with very similar code on a different page. I was testing the validity of $seller_email on the wrong page. On the page in question, it was in fact NOT being set. Once again, sorry. I should have posted the entire code.